# Simple PHP / cURL caching

Tags: php, curl

I'm getting content of remote page through cURL, I want to cache that page so that next time this page should not request cURL, and load from cache.

Cache should expire in one week.

Comment: memcached is a technology , its pretty easy to use. Now dont be that lazy to google 'memcahced'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved the same problem:

```
 <?php
//Set maximum age of cache file before refreshing it
$cacheLife = 15; // in seconds

//Set remote URL
$remoteURL = 'http://bravozulu.bz/';

//Set cacheName (We're assuming it's going to reside in the same directory as the caller script).

$cacheName = '_eventCache.php';

//Build the path to the cache
$cacheFileName = str_replace('/','\\', dirname(__FILE__)) . '\\'.$cacheName;


//Create Remote Retrieval / Cache Function - Reuse is good.
function FN_CacheEventPage($sourceURL, $destinationFile){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sourceURL);
 $fp = fopen($destinationFile, 'w');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
 curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
 fclose($fp);
 $ReturnFileContent = file_get_contents($destinationFile, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
 return $ReturnFileContent;
}

//Check to see if the file exists and ut still has Life

if (!file_exists($cacheFileName) or (time() - filemtime($cacheFileName) >= $cacheLife)){
    $cacheFileContent = FN_CacheEventPage($remoteURL, $cacheFileName);
}
else{
// If the cache file isn't there, or is too old, build a new one!   
  $cacheFileContent = file_get_contents($cacheFileName, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
}
include($cacheFileName);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Some pseudo code.

```
make a temp folder 


before each request check if page exists(with name==hash of URL) in the temp folder,  
if not,  
  fetch the page, 
  hash the URL,  
  save page in temp with the Hashed url file name.
else if exists
  get the temp file content
return contents
```

Update:
Code::

```
$curl_defaults = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0b11) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0b11',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
);

$curl_headers = array();
$curl_headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';
$curl_headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
$curl_headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';

function get($url, $data = "") {

    if (strlen($url) < 7) return;
    //echo "\n<br> Sending GET :: $url\n<br>";
    if (is_array($data)) $data = implode("&", $data);
    if (strpos($url, "?") > 5) $url .= "&$data";
    else
        $url .= "?$data";

    global $curl_defaults;

    $rep = array(":", "/", ".", "?", "&", "+", "=");
    $fn = dirname(__FILE__) . "/cache/" . md5(str_replace($rep, "", $url)) . ".txt";

    if (file_exists($fn) && @filesize($fn)>1){   //Add a file time check Here
        //echo "\n<br>From Cache FileSize :: "  . filesize($fn);
        return file_get_contents($fn);
    }


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_defaults);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    @unlink($fn);
    if(strlen($html) > 100)
        write2file($fn, $html);

    return $html;
}
```

You will probably need to make some changes.

Cache Dir : ./cache/

Comment: Add a Timestamp with your data so you can update it when its outdated